# How to get mysql query with table reference?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like below
[master and transaction table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux49a.png)

How to view table like below...?
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHFj5.png)

i have tried to use inner join or left join but cannot find like i need

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve it with the help of `LEFT JOIN`. Please try below queries:

For person id `P01`:

```
SELECT fruits.id_fruits, fruits.name, choice.person_id 
FROM fruits LEFT JOIN choice
ON choice.id_fruits = fruits.id_fruits 
AND choice.person_id = 'P01' ORDER BY fruits.id_fruits;
```

For person id `P02`:

```
SELECT fruits.id_fruits, fruits.name, choice.person_id 
FROM fruits LEFT JOIN choice
ON choice.id_fruits = fruits.id_fruits 
AND choice.person_id = 'P02' ORDER BY fruits.id_fruits;
```

For person id `P03`:

```
SELECT fruits.id_fruits, fruits.name, choice.person_id 
FROM fruits LEFT JOIN choice
ON choice.id_fruits = fruits.id_fruits 
AND choice.person_id = 'P03' ORDER BY fruits.id_fruits;
```

Try queries at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5RE6V6p9JLQ9VomCVXqKMa/1

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id_fruit,name,person_id FROM FROM Fruits LEFT JOIN choice USING (id_fruits) WHERE person_id=... ODER BY id_fruits;

or for all

SELECT id_fruit,name,person_id FROM FROM Fruits LEFT JOIN choice USING (id_fruits) ODER BY id_fruits,person_id;